Running gitlab job when particular variable is given while scheduling
This is my gitlab-ci.yml file
workflow:
  rules:
    - if: '$CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == "schedule" && $SCHEDULE_TYPE != "A"'
      when: never
    - when: always

stages:
  - Unit Test

Hello World:
  stage: Unit Test
  script:
    - echo "Hello"
  rules:
    - if: '$CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME == "master"'
  tags:
    - runner1

Scheduled Hello World:
  stage: Unit Test
  script:
    - echo "Hello"
  rules:
    - if: '$SCHEDULE_TYPE == "A"'
  tags:
    - runner1


I am scheduling the job and adding variable SCHEDULE_TYPE=A. In this case I only want Scheduled Hello World to run but currently in this both jobs are running since variable SCHEDULE_TYPE will be there in both since i am setting it while running. Hello World job since there are a lot of jobs running with similar rule if: '$CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME == "master"'. Anyone one has any idea regarding what change i can make.
